# How can I be sure of the result of NIntegrate when the integrand diverges at the boundaries?

Tags: numerical-integration, special-functions

I would like to perform the following integral:

$$I:=\int_0^1 d\alpha\ (1-\alpha)^{-1/2} \left(\log (1-\alpha) + \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(1,0,0,0)}(0,1,1,1-\alpha) - \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,1,0,0)}(0,1,1,1-\alpha) + \text{Hypergeometric2F1}^{(0,0,1,0)}(0,1,1,1-\alpha) \right) \tag{1}$$

Mathematica does not manage to compute an analytical result, so I thought I'd use `NIntegrate`. I get the following result:

$$I = -2.77259 \tag{2}$$

But I am bothered by the fact that the integrand has two divergences (in opposite directions) at $x=0$ and $x=1$, as can be seen in this plot:

[image]

I get the same result when setting `AccuracyGoal` to $\infty$. How do I know whether `NIntegrate` did that integral properly or not? I would think that changing the accuracy to a higher value should be a good check, since the result should change greatly if the values at $x=0$ and $x=1$ were contributing heavily (this is not happening in my case). Is that a good reasoning?

Comment: The default `AccuracyGoal` is `Infinity`.  Try raising `WorkingPrecision` to `24` or `32`.

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as *Mathematica* code instead of just images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: I would analyse the singularities at the boundaries using `Series`. This should show whether the integral is convergent (or not). You could then subtract a singular function from the integrand, to remove the singularities. What remains should be easy to integrate numerically and if you have chosen a suitable singular function, that can be integrated analytically.